# Execute External Console Application From Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to execute a console application from Dynamics CRM. What is the best way of doing that please?
The app should execute on daily basis.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to execute it in response to an event or does it run a regular schedule each day?

Comment: Just I need to run it on a regular schedule each day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to run a console application on a schedule then I've found Windows Task Scheduler to be excellent. Here's a link to MSDN: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766428.aspx

You can also use SQL Server Agent to run a console application but it requires a little more setup