# How to update the record automatically based on DateTime field in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a field called `Expired` that is set as a Date Only, Time-Zone independent, Date and Time field.

There is another field `Expiration Status` that looks at this field and is marked as Expired/Not Expired.

When I create an entity record and set the expiration date to `Today` I would expect the expiration status to only update to `Expired` the next day after 11:59:59 PM on Today. How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is to have a [nightly job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431521/execute-external-console-application-from-dynamics-crm) (Eg. Scribe package or console app in Task scheduler) to pull all the records that has **Today** as expiration date & set the status as **Expired**.

A "no-code" solution would be an UI workflow to wait until Expiry date & set the status. [Read more](https://www.powerobjects.com/2012/10/12/time-condition-based-workflows-in-crm-2011/). This is not a good choice.

Update:
Based on waiting workflows count the load increases in Async services, hence It’s [not a good choice](https://crmtipoftheday.com/121/dont-use-wait-conditions/).

[Community discussion on same topic](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/178961)

Comment: Have you looked at using a calculated field to be Expired or Not Expired based on your date field?

Comment: Can you expand on why the no-code solution is not a good choice?

Comment: @jasonscript thanks for pointing out the scope of improvement in answer.

Comment: @Nicknow Good point, but that calculated field is a virtual field & cannot be used for any other manipulation right?

Comment: Thanks for the updates Arun. Interesting read; the same link says that `timeouts` are better than `waits`. I've actually been a proponent of using `waits` because it means we don't have to setup another server (when working with online) to complete these types of tasks and all configuration is in a single place (i.e. CRM).